# Jacoco SonarQube Integration

Tags: java, sonarqube, maven-3, code-coverage, jacoco

I've spent a good couple of days trying to get SonarQube to display unit test code coverage from the Maven Jacoco plugin.

The error message I am stuck on is

```
[INFO] Analysing .../target/jacoco.exec
[WARNING] Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
```

The report under target/site/jacoco/index.html generates as expected and contains line highlighting and line numbers.  I have read that if no debug information is included in the compiled classes then the highlighting and line numbers will not show in this report.

I have read Maven includes debug information by default, however, just in case I included the following configuration in my projects maven-compiler-plugin setup

```
<configuration>
    <debug>true</debug>
    <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
</configuration>
```

I have the following properties in my settings.xml (host and login left out on purpose)

```
<properties>
    <sonar.host.url></sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.login></sonar.login>
    <sonar.ws.timeout>300</sonar.ws.timeout>
</properties>
```

I have the following configuration of my Jacoco plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>report</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My jacoco.exec is in the default location of target/jacoco.exec and is found correctly by SonarQube.

Relevant versions

Maven 3.2.2

Maven Compiler 3.5.1

Maven Surefire 2.19.1

Java 1.8.0_11

SonarQube Server 5.6

Jacoco Maven Plugin 0.7.7.201606060606

Mac OS X 10.10.5

Thanks in advance for the help!

---- EDIT ----

I am running the following maven commands

`mvn clean package`

`mvn sonar:sonar`

Comment: What command to you run to execute the analysis? For instance, take a look at my sample project which works, and most specifically at the "runAnalysis.sh" file => https://github.com/bellingard/fake-project-for-tests

Comment: I'm running `mvn clean package` and `mvn sonar:sonar`.  The prepare-agent goal is being executed pre test as seen by the following log.

    `[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:prepare-agent (default) @ event-service ---
    [INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:.../.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.7.201606060606/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=.../target/jacoco.exec`

Comment: Can you try to remove the JaCoCo configuration from your POM and run the same command as what you see in "runAnalysis.sh" file in my repo?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.  I tried your recommendation but I get the same warning messages `[WARNING] Coverage information was not collected. Perhaps you forget to include debug information into compiled classes?
`

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the article [here](http://dev.macero.es/2016/02/06/test-coverage-analysis-for-your-spring-boot-app/) and it just work for me, I have only updated the code to reflect the latest JaCoCo plugin version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

and adding JaCoCo agent to my POM plugins:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                 <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- JaCoCo configuration -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and running the following maven command (in Jenkins):

```
clean deploy $SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL
```

I have SonarQube 6.3.0.19869, Jenkins 2.46.1,  Maven Integration Plugin in Jenkins 2.15.1 (the older one caused JVM issues in my stack).